# INSERT to mysql wants to convert string to int, but I don't want too

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a table which holds some client information. I take this data and generate billing reports with it. The problem occurs when I want to Insert the string "A" into a varchar column titled "DiagCodePointer1". Every time I execute the command it tells me the conversion failed from nvarchar to int. Nothing in my code dims that string as an int so I don't understand why it's even trying. The destination column is a varchar.

With my limited knowledge I have triple checked my declarations of that string and the database columns to ensure they accept strings. I tried searching google for help but the results always display how to convert strings to int.
The error always breaks at the `Command.ExecuteNonQuery()`

```vb
Try
    connection.Close()
    connection.Open()
    Command = New OleDbCommand
    Command.Connection = connection
    Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Billing ([InsurancePlanName],[InsurancePayerID],[InsuranceStreetAddr],[InsuranceCity],[InsuranceState],[InsuranceZip],[InsuranceCityStateZip]" _
        & ",[PatientID],[PatientLast],[PatientFirst],[PatientDOB],[PatientMale],[PatientFemale],[InsuredLast],[InsuredFirst],[PatientStreetAddress],[PatientCity]" _
    & ",[PatientState],[PatientZip],[PatientRelationSELF],[InsuredStreetAddress],[InsuredCity],[InsuredState],[InsuredZip],[CondtionRelatedToEmlpoymentNo]," _
    & "[CondtionRelatedToAutoAccidentNo],[CondtionRelatedToOtherAccidentNo],[InsuredPolicyGroupOrFecaNumber],[InsuredDOB],[InsuredGenderMale],[InsuredGenderFemale]," _
    & "[IsThereAnotherHealthPlanBenefitNo],[PatientSignature],[PatientSignatureDate],[InsuredSignature],[OutsideLabChargesNo],[OutsideLabFees],[DiagCode1]," _
    & "[FromDateOfService1],[ToDateOfService1],[PlaceOfService1],[CPT1 (SERVICE CODE)],[DiagCodePointer1],[Charges1],[Units1],[RenderingPhysQualifier1],[FromDateOfService2]," _
    & "[ToDateOfService2],[PlaceOfService2],[CPT2],[DiagCodePointer2],[Charges2],[Units2],[RenderingPhysQualifier2],[TaxID],[EIN],[PatientAcctNumber]," _
    & "[AcceptAssignYes],[TotalCharges],[PhysicianSignature],[PhysicianSignatureDate],[PhysicianLast],[PhysicianFirst],[FacilityName],[FacilityStreetAddr]," _
    & "[FacilityCity],[FacilityState],[FacilityZip],[FacilityCityStateZip],[SupplierName],[SupplierStreetAddr],[SupplierCity],[SupplierState],[SupplierZip]," _
    & "[SupplierCityStateZip],[SupplierPhone],[SupplierNPI]) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"


    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Insuranceplanname", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Insuranceplanname
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsurancePayerID", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = payerid
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuranceStreetAddr", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insurancestreeaddress
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuranceCity", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insurancecity
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuranceState", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insurancestate
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuranceZip", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insurancezip
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuranceCityStateZip", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insurancecitystatezip
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientID", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = patientID
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientLast", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = patientlast
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientFirst", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = patientfirst
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientDOB", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Parse(patientDOB)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientMale", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = patientmale
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientFemale", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = patientfemale
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuredLast", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insuredlast
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuredFirst", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insuredfirst
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientStreetAddress", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = patientstreetaddress.ToString
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientCity", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = patientcity
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientState", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = patientstate
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientZip", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = patientzip
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientRelationSELF", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = patientrelationself
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuredStreetAddress", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insuredstreetaddress
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuredCity", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insuredcity
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuredState", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insuredstate
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuredZip", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insuredzip
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CondtionRelatedToEmlpoymentNo", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = conditionrelatedtoemploymentno
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CondtionRelatedToAutoAccidentNo", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = conditionrelatedtoautoaccidentno
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CondtionRelatedToOtherAccidentNo", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = conditionrelatedtootherno
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuredPolicyGroupOrFecaNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insuredpolicygrouporfecanumber
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuredDOB", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Parse(insuredDOB)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuredGenderMale", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insuredgendermale
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuredGenderFemale", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insuredgenderfemale
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("IsThereAnotherHealthPlanBenefitNo", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = isthereanotherhealthplanbenefitno
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientSignature", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = patientsignature
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientSignatureDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Parse(patientsignaturedate)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("InsuredSignature", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = insuredsignature
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("OutsideLabChargesNo", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = outsidelabchargesno
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("OutsideLabFees", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = outsidelabfees
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DiagCode1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = diagcode1
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FromDateOfService1", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Parse(fromdateofservice1)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ToDateOfService1", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Parse(todateofservice)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PlaceOfService1", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = placeofservice1
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CPT1 (SERVICE CODE)", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ServiceCode1
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DiagCodePointer1", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = diagcodepointer1
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Charges1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = charges12
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Units1", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = units1
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("RenderingPhysQualifier1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = renderingphysnpi1
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FromDateOfService2", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Parse(fromdateofservice2)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ToDateOfService2", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Parse(todateofservice2)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PlaceOfService2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = placeofservice2
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CPT2", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cpt2
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Charges2", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = charges99
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Units2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = units2
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DiagCodePointer2", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = diagcodepointer2
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("RenderingPhysQualifier2", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = renderingphysnpi2
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("TaxID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = taxid
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EIN", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = EIN
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientAcctNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = patientaccountnumber
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("AcceptAssignYes", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = acceptassignyes
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("TotalCharges", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = chargesfixed
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PhysicianSignature", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = physicianSignature
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PhysicianSignatureDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Parse(physiciansignaturedate)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PhysicianLast", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = physicianlast
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PhysicianFirst", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = physicianfirst
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FacilityName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = facilityname
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FacilityStreetAddr", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = facilitystreetaddress
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FacilityCity", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = facilitycity
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FacilityState", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = facilitystate
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FacilityZip", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = facilityzip
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FacilityCityStateZip", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = facilitycitystatezip
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SupplierName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = suppliername
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SupplierStreetAddr", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = supplierstreetaddress
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SupplierCity", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = suppliercity
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SupplierState", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = supplierstate
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SupplierZip", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = supplierzip
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SupplierCityStateZip", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = suppliercitystatezip
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SupplierPhone", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = supplierphone
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SupplierNPI", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = suppliernpi
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
    'End If

Catch ex As System.Exception
    If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & vbNewLine & ex.HResult & vbNewLine & ex.StackTrace & vbNewLine & ex.TargetSite.ToString)
    End If
End Try
```

This is the error I get in full:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'A' to data type int.
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at WindowsApp2.Form1.Ally_Report() in C:\Users\Lexington\source\repos\WindowsApp2\WindowsApp2\Form1.vb:line 1680
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader ExecuteReaderInternal(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.String)

All I want it to do is literally insert the letter "A" into the specific columns "DiagCodePointer1" and "DiagCodePointer2".

Comment: What is the data type of those 2 fields in the schema

Comment: Your parameters are in a different order.  So the values you think you're trying to insert into some columns, you're actually trying to insert into other columns.

Comment: your absolutely correct, I'm going to try this, thank you...Ill post back with results

Comment: You might want to consider re-writing your `INSERT` query as a stored procedure. Then you can simply reference your parameters directly in the procedure. It also allows you to change your business logic in the database without having to recode your vb.net application if that's ever necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much David, that fixed it. I didn't see that at all and I'm glad it was a simple error. Thank you again!

Comment: If you are using MySql why are you using an OleDb provider? MySql has its own provider that will recognize parameter names.

Comment: Now that I look closer, I see that your database is MySql, your command is OleDb, and your datatypes are SqlDbType. 3 different providers! Also I see no overload of .AddWithValue that takes a type as the second parameter. That would be the .Add method.